# ValueError- Scratch Training for Multiple Output in tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a ML models which have 3 output. Each of them have passed into a SoftMax player. I'm trying to train the model from custom scratch with training loop in keras. My generator output are something like this:

```
x,y = (batch_size, h,w,c), [(batch_size, 2), (batch_size, 8), (batch_size, 10)]
```

As you notice, each of the 3 output has different numbers of labels. First output layer has 2 labels output, second one has 8 and last one has 10.

---

Here is the code snippet,

```py
epochs = 1
optimizer   = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05)
loss_fn     = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

train_acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
val_acc_metric   = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()

@tf.function
def train_step(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

        # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
        train_loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)

    # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
    # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(train_loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

    # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
    # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

    # Update training metric.
    train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
    
    return train_loss_value
```

And,

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_generator):
        train_loss_value = train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)

    # Reset metrics at the end of each epoch
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()
```

When I run the code using `fit` method, it works nicely. But approaching with custom scratch training like above throws following error message:

```
    ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 8 and 10. Shapes are [64,8] and [64,10].
        From merging shape 1 with other shapes. 
for '{{node categorical_crossentropy/packed}} = Pack[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT, axis=0](net_2/gra/Softmax, net_2/vow/Softmax, net_2/cons/Softmax)' 
with input shapes: [64,2], [64,8], [64,10].
```

I suspect, I am not handling properly the computation of loss in here: `loss_fn(y, logits)`. `y` has 3 output, `logits` has also 3 output. When I pass `loss_fn(y[0], logits[0]`, it works for the first output from rest.

However, any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.